# How to start a boost::thread running a member function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a real time controller application with a number of hardware devices of different types connected.

All devices share a lot of code, but each has also some device type specific stuff. I'm trying to write this code to be easy to extend with new types of hw.

Each connected device should have an event manager function running in a separate thread.
I would like to keep the common stuff in a base class, lets call it "Device" and just put the hardware specific code in the derived classes.

So I create a Device base class with the common stuff and make the event manager a pure virtual, and then each derived class implements it.

Then at system start I create a vector of all the connected hardware devices, and push pointers to instances of the appropriate derived class into it.

Now I would like to start a boost::thread for each instance in the vector, and each thread should execute the event manager function from that instance in the vector.

So I try something like:

```
Class Device {
...
    boost::thread thread;
    void manager() = 0;
...
}

Class SpecificDevice1 : public Device {
...
    void manager();
}

SpecificDevice1::manager() {
...do stuff here...
}

Class SpecificDevice2 : public Device {
...
    void manager();
}

SpecificDevice2::manager() {
...do stuff here...
}

Class Config {
...
    std::vector<Device*> devices;
...
}

Config config;
...config.devices get populated with pointers to instances of SpecificDevice1 and SpecificDevice2...

for( auto &device : config.devices ) {
    device->thread = boost::thread( device->manager );
};
```

I have tried many different permutation of this but I always end up with

error: no matching function for call to 'boost::thread::thread()'

...even if I dynamic_cast device to a pointer to the appropriate SpecificDeviceX class, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boost::thread` constructor needs a function pointer, *and* an instance to the actual object (for the `this` pointer in the member function).

For this use can use the [Thread Constructor with arguments](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor):

```
device->thread = boost::thread(&Device::manager, device);
```

The first argument is a pointer to the member function, and the second is a pointer to an instance of `Device`.

There is another change you must do for this to work though, and that is to make the `manager` function `virtual`, for the proper function would be called:

```
Class Device {
    ...
    boost::thread thread;
    virtual void manager() = 0;
    ...
}
```

By the way, since you are using a compiler supporting C++11, I suggest you change to [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) if possible.

Comment: I don't think this code works. It seems the boost::thread call does not pick up the implementation of the pure virtual function from the SpecificDeviceX. I get a "pure virtual function called" error.

Comment: OK, that was because I followed all suggestions at once, including switching to std::thread. Using boost::thread it works fine!